# decimal to 8 bit binary conversion in c++

Tags: c++, binary

I am working on decimal to binary conversion. I can convert them, using 
char bin_x [10];
  itoa (x,bin_x,2);
but the problem is, i want answer in 8 bits. And it gives me as, for example x =5, so output will be 101, but i want 00000101. 
Is there any way to append zeros in the start of array? or is it possible to get answer in 8 bits straight away? I am doing this in C++

Comment: I removed the C tag, as you state that you are doing this in C++.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++, the easiest way is *probably* to use a `std::bitset`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main() { 
    int x = 5;

    std::bitset<8> bin_x(x);
    std::cout << bin_x;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

> 00000101

Comment: can you please explain it a little, shall i run for loop for the value of "x"?

Comment: @bijlikamasla: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you want to generate different values of `x`, then yes a `for` loop would usually be a reasonable way to generate them. In case it helps, I've modified the code so it's a complete program you can run...

Comment: i was wondering, if there is some way to convert hexadecimal to binary using bitset?

Comment: @bijlikamasla: convert the hex to some integer type using something like strtol, then the integer type to binary using bitset.

Answer (score 0):

To print out the bits of a single digit, you need to do the following:

```
//get the digit (in this case, the least significant digit)
short digit = number % 10; //shorts are 8 bits

//print out each bit of the digit
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    if(0x80 & digit) //if the high bit is on, print 1
        cout << 1;
    else
        cout << 0; //otherwise print 0
    digit = digit << 1; //shift the bits left by one to get the next highest bit.
}
```

Comment: i didnt understand this. Can you please explain it a little. Shall I run a loop over it, for the values of i? and what is "number" here? is it "X"?

Comment: it is also giving me following errors: 1> error C2039: 'bitset' : is not a member of 'std' 2> error C2065: 'bitset' : undeclared identifier 3>error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Comment: error is resolved, after i included its header file. But now, it is not giving me correct output. It is giving:  Binary form of X = 1001010
and 8-bit representation is 0000000000000001000000100000001100000100000001010000011000000111

Comment: Please post your code in your question.  I cannot help you with your code if I cannot see your code.

Answer (score 0):

`itoa()` is not a standard function so it's not good to use it if you want to write portable code.

You can also use something like that:

```
std::string printBinary(int num, int bits) {
    std::vector<char> digits(bits);
    for (int i = 0; i < bits; ++i) {
        digits.push_back(num % 2 + '0');
        num >>= 1;
    }
    return std::string(digits.rbegin(), digits.rend());
}

std:: cout << printBinary(x, 8) << std::endl;
```

However I must agree that using `bitset` would be better.

Comment: thanks. i was wondering, if there is some way to convert hexadecimal to binary using bitset?

Comment: @bijlikamasla You can first read hexadecimal to a string using e.g. `sscanf` or istream's `>>` operator. And the use bitset as Jerry Coffin wrote